# Average Calculator [ rounding issues ]

Tags: java

I have been assigned a task to create a average calculator, unfortunately each time a average is done I get either one too many which doesn't fix the issue when I do number -- OR, the average is completely off.

```
import java.util.*; 

public class Mean
{
    public static void main()
    {
        Scanner inputLine = new Scanner(System.in);
        int total = 0, number, counter = 0;
        double average;

        System.out.println ("Enter your numbers, press 0 to launch");


        while (inputLine.nextInt() != 0)
        {
            number = inputLine.nextInt();
            if(number >= 1)
            {
                total = total + number;
                counter++;
            }
        }


        average = total/counter-1;
        System.out.println ("Your Average is : " + average);

    }
}
```

Comment: You are performing integer math (which results in an integer), you then widen that integer to a `double`. Fix it by doing math on a `double`. Something like, `average = ((double) total)/counter;`

Comment: Just tried that, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,0 = 6 still strangely.

Answer (score 4):

1. You are reading an `int` from the `Scanner` twice per loop.  The `while` loop reads an `int` to make sure it's not `0`, but then the body of the `while` loop reads a second `int` and only counts that second `int`.

Assign the result of the first `nextInt` call to a variable in the while loop condition, and use that variable in the body for the calculations.

2. You are subtracting 1 from your average calculation.  There's no reason for that.  Don't do it.
3. You are performing Java's integer division, which will truncate any decimals.  Cast one of the operands to `/` to `double` to force floating-point calculations.

```
while ( (number = inputLine.nextInt() ) != 0)
{
    if(number >= 1)
    {
        total = total + number;
        counter++;
    }
}
average = (double) total / counter;
```

You may want to add code for a condition where the user entered no items, to prevent dividing by 0.